# Fetch users with their unread messages with Laravel Join vs Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel

I 'm working on a chat application. I am fetching all the users to show in the sidebar. With each user fetched I also want to show an indication of **unread messages** from any user. I have the **messages** table like this.

---

**id** | **user_id** | **receiver_id** | **message** | **is_read**

---

and **standard users table** of Laravel. I achieved it with the following **join** in the the controller method.

```
public function users_join()
{
    // get logged in user
    $user = Auth::id();
    // left join to get all users all time
    return DB::table('users')->where('users.id', '!=', $user)
        ->leftJoin('messages', function ($join) use ($user) {
            // first evaluate where in below function
            $join->on('users.id', '=', 'messages.user_id')
                // filter messages sent to current user
                ->where('messages.receiver_id', '=', $user)
                // get only those messages which are unread
                ->where('messages.is_read', '=', 0);
        })->select('users.*', 'messages.user_id', 'messages.receiver_id', 'messages.message'
            , 'messages.is_read')
        // finally grouped by email to get only 10 records from users table
        ->orderBy('messages.created_at', 'DESC')->groupBy('email')->get();
}
```

Now I want to do it with the **Laravel Eloquent**. I can't think of any other way of doing this without using loop. Here is the code for that.

```
public function users_eloquent()
{
    // get current user
    $current_user = Auth::id();
    // each through all users except current
    $users = User::all()->except($current_user)->each(function ($user) use ($current_user) {
        // laravel relationship
        $user->messages = $user->messages()
            // messages sent to me
            ->where('receiver_id', $current_user)
            // unread message sent to me
            ->where('is_read', 0)
            // get latest unread message
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            // first latest message
            ->first();
    });
    // send back the response
    return $users;
}
```

My **User** Model is like this

```
public function messages()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

and just in case, my **Message** Model is like this

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

I want to achieve it with **Eloquent** without using each loop. How can I do this?

I have all the users in sidebar and their unread mark. Below is the attached screenshot.

Thanks!

[image: chat application picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop all the users.

You can find the user except `current_user` by `where()` method on Eloquent model before it become collection.

And use `with()` to get the latest msg for those users:

```php
$current_user = Auth::id();

return User::where('id', '<>', $current_user)
            ->with(['messages' => function($q) use ($current_user) {
                      $q->where('receiver_id', $current_user)
                        ->where('is_read', 0)
                        ->latest()
                        ->first();
            }])->get();
```

Comment: It worked. I didn't know you could do 'where' with 'with'. I was looking for this kind of solution. You increased my knowledge. Thanks a lot!